# How to migrate a custom User model to Devise in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I'm new to Rails and have completed Michael Hartl's online tutorial and followed his steps to write the User model without using a gem as he recommended. I'd like to switch my user model/views etc... to Devise so that I can use some of its built-in features.

The problem is that I'm not sure if I should delete the codes before installing Devise gem or just add the gem onto of my code. I've searched online for a solution but a lot of the solution are outdated and haven't worked. Any help or link will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Devise will modify an existing model. So if your model is `User` just install Devise and then run

```
rails generate devise User
```

As described in the README. The main thing to be aware of is that Devise works best if the email field is the attribute `email`, if you've called it something like `email_address` I'd suggest you rename it before installing Devise.

Comment: I take it you don't need to run rails generate devise:install first?

Comment: You still need to run the generator - that sets some other stuff up. Just follow the README for a standard install.

Comment: Thank you for the help.